# Adding a value to the predefined array for uitableview iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

How can i add a new value to the predefined array for uitableview while clicking add button?

```
-(IBAction)addNewBreed:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertView *addAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Add New Item" message:@"\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Add",nil];
    UITextField *addTextField=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12,45,260,25)];
    [addTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    [addTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    addTextField.clearButtonMode=UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    [addAlert addSubview:addTextField];

    [addAlert show];


}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    NSString *buttonTitle=[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Add"]) 
    {

         //HERE WHAT CODE SHOULD I ADD,MY ARRAY NAME 'ar'       
    }
    else
        return;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to add object at some specific index in uitableview ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your array is a `NSMutableArray`, then you can use following code:

```
[ar addObject: addTextField.text];//you may also enter any string here
  [yourTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: i want a user input value?pls help @iPhone Developer